# Form inside page in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to make a DetailView page, like:

```
class TaskDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'todo/task_detail.html'
```

and place form inside this page, so user can add this task. 
Its easy, if create new page for this form:

forms.py

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = task
        fields = __all__
```

views.py

```
def TaskForm_view(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            task.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = TaskForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'todo/add_task.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/add/', 'todo.views.TaskForm_view', name='add')
```

but how to create a DetailView page with form inside? I cant find an exemple, help plz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the form in a context variable, so you can access to it from the template as: *form*

```
class TaskDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'todo/task_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = TaskForm()
        return context
```

Comment: TY, form is on page now! But how can i add submit button?) I still cant save it.

Comment: You need to add the button manually on the template. You have some examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: Thanks! Dont get at first time, that it works as usual form now)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView.

DetailView are designed to display data.

[Here is described Form handling with class-based views in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: TY for answer, I have task list page (ListView) and page for tasks details (DetailView), its similar to django tutorial. But now problem is add this task to my list.

Comment: You have tasks (Task) and some users (YouUser model). To assign task to You or somebody else You don't need attach additional form to DetailView. Instead of that send ajax request and handle this in separate view.
  def your_ajax_view(request): 
    if not request.is_ajax(): 
      return